# Outlook AutoComplete Email List

Tags: c#, autocomplete, office365, vsto, outlook-addin

I want extract list all autocomplete email addresses in outlook 2016 (office 365) using C#.
I am using following code;

```
NameSpace olNS = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
MAPIFolder inboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByEntryID);
PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;
byte[] bytes = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

When I execute above code I get the following error
Cannot create StorageItem in this folder. Either the folder is read-only, or a storage item is not allowed in this folder.

Please help in this regard
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass` instead of `OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByEntryID`:

```
NameSpace olNS = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
MAPIFolder inboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;
byte[] bytes = (byte[])propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

The code listed above works like a charm on my machine!

However, be aware, the `GetStorage` returns an error if the store type of the folder is not supported. The following stores return an error when GetStorage is called:

- Hotmail store
- Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) stores
- Delegate stores
- Public folder stores

Comment: thanks for you help. can you tell me how to get email addresses from bytes

Comment: That's another question. You need to create a new post at SO.

Comment: I have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390631/email-list-from-bytes

Comment: hi Eugene Astafiev, I used your code but still error Cannot create StorageItem in this folder. Either the folder is read-only, or a storage item is not allowed in this folder.

Comment: the GetStorage returns an error if the store type of the folder is not supported